# Unable to Inject Dependency ngMaterial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6, angularjs-material

I am looking to develop an application that uses both dirPagination and AngularJS material. However, I am unable to inject the `ngMaterial` dependency into my application. The `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` dependency works fine, but as soon as I add `ngMaterial`, the AngularJS application crashes.

Here is a Plunker with an example (https://plnkr.co/edit/7N7i9TnMc77Nz6xlNhuk?p=preview). In app.js, which is where I instantiate the module, both dependencies are there. If the line reads:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ngMaterial']);
```

Then AngularJS crashes and the page reads {{hello}}. However, since in the controller, I have set `$scope.hello` to `"Hello Plunker!"`, if the line reads:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Then the page displays "Hello Plunker!".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to include **angular.js** before any other script that is going to use angular. Here you add **script.js** before **angular.js**
2. You also need to use the same versions of angular modules **angular-animate, angular-aria, angular-messages** as that of **angular.js** version
   Here you used **1.6.4 version** of angular.js

   ```
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
   ```

You can check for the modifications I made to your plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/En0YaiaiqD1MPPOydAf8?p=preview

Also there were errors for cross domain request for bootstrap.min.css which can be easily fixed by using

> https://

cdn

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the script for material.css, and the order is wrong.

```
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxk5JyTjvuivQoxF4M8G?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

This is a working demo, was having version issue and also order of declaring `JS` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
       <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp">
      <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
        <md-toolbar class="md-warn">
         <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2 class="md-flex">HTML 5</h2>
         </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.hello = "Hello Plunker!";
   });


   </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that `angular-material.js` requires `angular-animate.js` and `angular-aria.js`, and the latter two should go before `angular-material.js`. `angular-messages.js` doesn't seem to be required.